# Apache Ignite join bug?

Tags: ignite

I have an issue with a join SQL query in Apache Ignite. Is this a bug or I missed something?

The following query unexpectedly doesn't return any result:

```
 SELECT * FROM PERSON AS p, ACCOUNT AS a
 WHERE 
 p.ACCOUNT_ID = a.id
 AND 
 p.ID = '4nFwLM9FRxKZJb4V9vtdlw'
```

When I include a condition for the account, the row is returned:

```
 SELECT * FROM PERSON AS p, ACCOUNT AS a
 WHERE 
 p.ACCOUNT_ID = a.id
 AND 
 p.ID = '4nFwLM9FRxKZJb4V9vtdlw'
 AND a.id = 'wZvcAnbBSpOps9oteH-Oxw'
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE umm_person (
    id varchar(36) NOT NULL primary key,
    account_id varchar(36) NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX idx_person_account_id ON umm_person (account_id);

CREATE TABLE main_account (
    id varchar(36) NOT NULL primary key,
);
```

I tested with Apache Ignite 2.14.0 and 2.10.0, using a single node:

```
public class IgniteNode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setClientMode(false);
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        cfg.setCacheConfiguration();
        Ignition.start(cfg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is described in some detail in [this issue's comments](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13019).

In short, your data isn't colocated.

For `JOIN` to work, one of the three must be true:

- Both tables are `PARTITIONED`, and the `JOIN` condition is the affinity key of both of them.
- At least one of the tables is `REPLICATED`.
- `distributedJoins=true` is set.

You might think that on a single node cluster, all data is colocated anyway but it is not actually true. And depending on the query, the SQL engine may change how to search the data - that won't affect the result when everything is configured correctly but leads to different results in your setup when you add another condition.